# simple onclick NOT inline

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm using interwoven's teamsite, I'm trying to figure out how to use some javascript with it, what I'm trying to do is a simple onlick function, where you click one div and it changes the background color of another div.  I don't want to use jquery for this.  I have a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/yeYZm/1/  and the script I tried was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeColor (){
btn_div.onClick= changed_div.style.backgroundColor = '#242424';
}
</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Probably [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) might help...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the doodle.

```
document.getElementById('btn_div').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('changed_div').style.backgroundColor = '#242424';
}
```

And the doodle link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeYZm/3/)